# Type of an IronPython object

Tags: python, ironpython

I have a question about type of an object in IronPython. I've created .NET type in C# (I've created MyClass class) and compiled my class library project. Let's say I've created TestLibrary.dll in that kind of way. Then I referenced this library in my IronPython project and created IronPython class which inherits from .NET type which is in my TestLibrary.dll. My code looks like this:

```
import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(r'C:\TestLibrary\TestLibrary\bin\Debug\TestLibrary.dll')

from TestLibrary import *

class TestPythonClass(MyClass):
    def doSomething(self):
        print('Hello')
```

But when I created an object of my TestPythonClass I discovered that type of that object is 'IronPython.NewTypes.TestLibrary.MyClass_15$16'.

```
testPythonClass = TestPythonClass()
typeToString = testPythonClass.GetType().ToString()
```

Can anyone provide me with some additional information why type of my IronPython object is actually type which is declared into TestLibrary.dll? And why type is not the TestPythonClass?

Comment: The Python type and the .NET type of your object are different things. If you want the Python type, use the `type` function.

Answer (score 2):

IronPython use the reflexion to handle .NET types.

The `.GetType()` method calls the type from CLR. Its the same as calling

```
clr.GetClrType(type(testPythonClass))
```

It should be different if you call

```
type(testPythonClass)
```

you will get the python class.